# Desktop folder not showing all the shortcuts I have on my desktop

Tags: windows-8

I just noticed when I let the program install their shortcuts - these shortcuts don't display in `users/<username>/desktop` folder.

When I create them myself, by right clicking on the program executable -> create shortcuts, it displays in a "desktop" folder. So the question is - why can't I see all of my desktop shortcuts in a `users/<username>/desktop` folder?

Where does Windows store them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the version of windows, they might be stored in the all users/public folder.
For example windows 8, stores them in C:\Users\Public\Desktop, by default desktop folder is hidden, so you might have to change the visibility first.

Comment: Yeah, in this public folder only installed by the programms shortcuts, thanks! It's not like with windows7 when it was only one place users/myname/desktop? They changed that in windows8?

Comment: It was like this since Vista. In XP this folder was called *All Users*.

Comment: Some installers let you choose to "Install for all users" or not - this determines which area the shortcuts are installed.